# Deleted post from 2015?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I believe I posted a question in early May or late April of 2015 and I can't find it here now. Might it have been deleted? If so, could a record of its content and comments and answers be given to me?

Comment: There are 2 answers here. You didn't reply on one of them. I'd like to know whether it answered your question.

Comment: @SueVanHattum : I ultimately figured this out: I had the time right but it was to a different stackexchange site.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to prove a negative, but I was unable to find one.

I looked in the Internet Archive to see if such a question had been listed on your profile in September 2015, but the questions listed there are still alive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150906074533/https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/205/michael-hardy

I then used this method to look through your reputation for "question removed:" https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226224/164838 and found no missing posts. It's possible I missed it, but with the amount of information you've given and my knowledge of the site, I didn't find anything. Maybe you remember what the post was about and can use one of the two methods I've outlined above to find it.

Good luck.

Comment: I also looked here: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/205 and I'm not sure if you can access that page, but it shows no deleted questions for me.

Comment: On June 11 I flagged one of my questions with an inquiry about this, since flagging was the only way I knew to contact the moderators privately. It was declined with the following message: "I don't know if someone deleted one of your questions, but this isn't the right use of flags. Please don't use them this way." Is there some reason why the person who wrote that did not inform me of some other way to contact the moderators? Is anything more obvious than the fact that no other way of contacting the moderators privately is made known to users?

Comment: I don't know what you want from me, Michael. You used flags incorrectly, and I told you this. Then you used meta correctly, and I helped you there. Then you used meta again correctly, and I helped you again. I'm not a superhuman robot. I'm helping you repeatedly, often spending significant time doing so. I'm not a paid employee and I'm not a company representative, although StackExchange did send me a shirt once. I've done everything I can for you.

Comment: I find it strange to hear about "superhuman" when I talking about something so routine that takes a couple of seconds. Did you somehow not know that when I used a flag it was because it was the only way I knew? No other way is made publicly known.

Comment: I don't know what your complaint is or what you want; it seems like your complaint is that moderators are difficult to contact. However, I am not a StackExchange engineer and I am not in charge of designing the systems here. You are very interested in finding some work you did in the past, and out of respect for that, I am trying to help you. What do you want from me? If it is "make it easier to contact moderators," my answer is "no; I am busy." If it is "Find my question from 2015," I have tried my best. Please let me know what you want.

Comment: I am not sure why you speak of a "complaint." I would not suggest that you make it _easier_ to contact the moderators as much as that you make it _possible_ to contact the moderators. If flagging is the only known method, then it seems inappropriate to tell people that a particular topic that it is appropriate to bring up with the moderators is not an appropriate topic for flagging.

Comment: I have no other help for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisCunningham for looking those things up.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to the "Questions" subtab on the "Activity" tab on your profile page, and then click on "[Deleted questions](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current)" at the bottom of your questions list.
This will bring up the list of all your deleted questions.

There is a similar link on the "Answers" subtab that will bring up all your "[Deleted answers](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current)".

###### Notes

1. The above URLs use the format `/users/deleted-questions/current` and `/users/deleted-answers/current`. So, if a logged in user clicks on these links, it will take them to *their* list of deleted questions and answers, and not that of the OP.
2. This feature was released on [2022-01-12](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184), so it is a relatively recent addition. Earlier, only a limited set of deleted questions and answers were accessible through these pages.